# How to mute twilio calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am able to mute the sound going into the microphone, but not the sound coming out of the speakers.  To be specific, I'm only trying to mute the Twilio call, not other sounds in the browser, and certainly not system sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the call is between 2 persons only, then this can be done by creating a conference in twilio and muting the other person during the call. This will make the server reject the voice input from the other party.

However, to completely stop the sound on your side local, i would suggest using javascript to alter the flash player privileges to restrict the hardware access when you want the call to be muted.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but probably the only answer available for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Its straightforward using the Javascript 1.4 library, without needing conference calls etc.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection

e.g.

```
Twilio.Device.activeConnection().mute(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is the exact and simple solution.

Comment: When the call is established, and I run the code, the console log returns error: "Twilio.Device.activeConnection(...) is null"

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example

```
  $scope.togglePublishAudio = function togglePublishAudio() {
      $log.debug('Toggling publish audio');

      if (activeRoom.localParticipant.media.isMuted === false) {        
        $scope.isMuted = true;        
        activeRoom.localParticipant.media.mute();
      } else {
        $scope.isMuted = false;
        activeRoom.localParticipant.media.unmute();
      }

    };
```

In new Version of twilio

```
  var localMedia = room.localParticipant;
  localMedia.tracks.forEach(function (track) {
    if (track.isEnabled) {
      track.disable();
      $scope.isPaused = true;
    } else {
      track.enable();
      $scope.isPaused = false;
    }
  });
```